# Transpose a colum into a line inside the same table using a keyboard and trackpad combination

Tags: numbers

Given the data on this table

[image]

I type the formula "=B2" in cell "D2" and get

[image]

Now, I want to select cell "D2" and somehow get the formulas "=B3" in "E2", "=B4" in "F2", and so on, thus resulting in the table

[image]

How can this be done by selecting cell "D2", and with a keyboard + trackpad combination get the resulting table with the generated formulas?

Thanks

Comment: This is much better than the original question and actually is understandable. You should delete the original question and get back the lost reputation points. That said, I too would like to know if it's possible to be done, but I don't think it is. +1 for a good question anyway. I tried selecting D2 and dragging it with all the modifier keys combinations and no joy.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks! One image is worth 1000 words, and three are even better. I will follow your advice and delete the other question.